# Setting facet-specific breaks in stat_contour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to show a contour plot using `ggplot` and `stat_contour` for two categories of my data with `facet_grid`. I want to highlight a particular level based on the data. Here's an analogous dummy example using the usual `volcano` data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)    
v.plot <- volcano %>% reshape2::melt(.) %>% 
      mutate(dummy = Var1 > median(Var1)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, z = value)) + 
      stat_contour(breaks = seq(90, 200, 12)) + 
      facet_grid(~dummy)
```

**Plot 1:**
[image]

Let's say within each factor level (here east and west halves, I guess), I want to find the mean height of the volcano and show that. I can calculate it manually:

```
volcano %>% reshape2::melt(.) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = Var1 > median(Var1)) %>% 
  group_by(dummy) %>% 
  summarise(h.bar = mean(value))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  dummy    h.bar
  <lgl>    <dbl>
1 FALSE 140.7582
2  TRUE 119.3717
```

Which tells me that the mean heights on each half are 141 and 119. I can draw BOTH of those on BOTH facets, but not just the appropriate one on each side.

```
v.plot + stat_contour(breaks = c(141, 119), colour = "red", size = 2)
```

**Plot 2:**
[image]

And you can't put `breaks=` inside an `aes()` statement, so passing it in as a column in the original dataframe is out. I realize with this dummy example I could probably just do something like `bins=2` but in my actual data I don't want the mean of the data, I want something else altogether.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edits @beetroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made another attempt at this problem and came up with a partial solution, but I'm forced to use a different `geom`.

```
volcano %>% reshape2::melt(.) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = Var1 > median(Var1)) %>% 
  group_by(dummy) %>% 
  mutate(h.bar = mean(value),                      # edit1
         is.close = round(h.bar) == value) %>%     #
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, z = value)) + 
  stat_contour(breaks = seq(90, 200, 12)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red", size = 3,             # edit 2
           aes(alpha = is.close)) +                #
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0,1)) +           #
  facet_grid(~dummy)
```

In `edit 1` I added a `mutate()` to the above block to generate a variable identifying where `value` was "close enough" (rounded to the nearest integer) to the desired highlight point (the mean of the data for this example).

In `edit2` I added `geom_point`s to show the grid locations with the desired value, and hid the undesired ones using an `alpha` of 0 or totally transparent.

**Plot 3:** [image: Point highlights]

The problem with this solution is that it's very gappy, and trying to bridge those with `geom_path` is a jumbled mess. I tried coarser rounding as well, and it just made things muddy.

Would love to hear other ideas! Thanks